# Convert code for digital signature from Java to C# with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, encryption, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pkcs#8

I'm working on creating an sso with a third party vendor, and part of the process is generating a Base64-encoded digital signature to include as part of a url string.  The vendor's documentation includes sample Java code, but I'm trying to convert the sample to C# with bouncycastle.

The private key is generated through a page on the vendor's website, and is in PKCS#8 format.  An example (not my actual key) would look like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here is the vendor's sample Java code:

```
public static String createSecurityToken(String privateKey,
int referrer_id, int external_id) throws Exception {
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
String msg = String.format("referrer_id=%d&ee:external_id=%d&timestamp=%s",
referrer_id, external_id, timestamp);
String signature = generateMessageSignature(msg, privateKey);
return signature;
}

public static String generateMessageSignature(String message, String 
privateKeyPkcs8) throws
Exception {
privateKeyPkcs8 = privateKeyPkcs8.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
privateKeyPkcs8 = privateKeyPkcs8.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
privateKeyPkcs8 = privateKeyPkcs8.replaceAll("\n", "");
byte [] decoded = Base64.decode(privateKeyPkcs8);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey pri = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
byte[] data = message.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sig.initSign(pri);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();
return toBase64(signature);
}
```

Using some other examples I found as references, this is where I got to with my code:

```
protected static string createSecurityToken(string privateKey, int referrer_id, string external_id)
{
    long timestamp = Environment.TickCount;
    string msg = String.Format("referrer_id={0}&ee:external_id={1}&timestamp={2}", referrer_id, external_id, timestamp);
    string signature = generateMessageSignature(msg, privateKey);

    return signature;
}


protected static string generateMessageSignature(string message, string privateKeyPkcs8)
{
    //per documentation: the message encoding must be converted to "UTF-16LE" and the message signed using the "SHA1withRSA" algorithm

    privateKeyPkcs8 = privateKeyPkcs8.Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    privateKeyPkcs8 = privateKeyPkcs8.Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    privateKeyPkcs8 = privateKeyPkcs8.Replace("\n", "");
    byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyPkcs8);

    AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(decoded);
    RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
    RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
    rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
    rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();

    ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");

    sig.Init(true, rsaKeyParameters);

    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);

    sig.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    byte[] signature = sig.GenerateSignature();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
}
```

When I try to generate and output the signature with pre-defined test parameters, I get this error:

Bad sequence size: 3
Parameter name: seq

pointing to this line of code:

AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(decoded);

When I tried researching this error, there were references to X509 certificates, but I'm not exactly sure what to do there.  Any help would be much appreciated.

---

UPDATE: Per James' comment, all I had to do was change PublicKeyFactory to PrivateKeyFactory and it worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: Since it's a private key you have perhaps you should use the PrivateKeyFactory class.

Comment: *headdesk*  That was it, thank you!!!